# Otimizar sequência de if

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura e gostaria de otimizar o código dos if, já existem várias partes iguais. Então fiz um foreach. Mas a variável do tipo ExpandoObject, não sei como lidar com ela de forma genérica para receber o valor da função.

Se alguém puder e souber me ajudar, agradeço. Segue abaixo o código anterior e a minha tentativa:

```
//Antes
dynamic line = new ExpandoObject();
line.Filial = ""                
line.Cidade = "";
line.Cep = "";
line.Uf = "";
line.Cliente = "";              
line.Cnpj = "";

if (columnIndexes.Contains (Filial))
  line.Filial = GetValue(table, columnIndexes, Filial, i);

if (columnIndexes.Contains (Cidade))
  line.VendasQuantidade = GetValue(table, columnIndexes, Cidade, i);

if (columnIndexes.Contains (Cep))
  line.Cep = GetValue(table, columnIndexes, Cep, i);

if (columnIndexes.Contains (Uf))
  line.Uf = GetValue(table, columnIndexes, Uf, i);

if (columnIndexes.Contains (Cliente))
  line.Cliente = GetValue(table, columnIndexes, Cliente, i);

if (columnIndexes.Contains (Cnpj))
  line.Cnpj = GetValue(table, columnIndexes, Cnpj, i);
```

---

```
//Depois
var values = new List<string>() {Cidade, Cep, Uf, Cliente, Cnpj, Filial };  

foreach (var value in values)
{
  if (columnIndexes.ContainsValue(value))
  {
    lineToInsert[value] = GetMapValue(table, columnIndexes, value, i);(não funciona)
    lineToInsert[value.ToString] = GetMapValue(table, columnIndexes, value, i);(não funciona)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem você quer verificar se uma propriedade dinâmica de um `ExpandoObject` e setar um valor é isso?

Adaptando seu código seria algo assim:

```
dynamic line = new ExpandoObject();
        line.Filial = "";             
        line.Cidade = "";
        line.Cep = "";
        line.Uf = "";
        line.Cliente = "";              
        line.Cnpj = "";

        var fields = new List<string>() { "Cidade", "Cep", "Uf", "Cliente", "Cnpj", "Filial", "Algum" };
        // dicionário com as propriedades do ExpandoObject
        var dicLine = (IDictionary<string, object>)line;

        foreach(var f in fields)
        {
            if (dicLine.ContainsKey(f))
            {
                dicLine[f] = "teste";
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("line.Cep=" + line.Cep);
```

Basta mudar o valor "teste" pelo valor que você tiver pra setar no seu código.

Coloquei um exemplo funcional aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OatFbt

Comment: Muito Obrigada! Era exatamente isso estava faltando converter em dicionário. E isso acontece porque antes ele era um objeto e eu estava tentando trabalhar com ele como se fosse um dicionário, certo?

Comment: Sim, no fundo como é um objeto não "tipado", não pode ser como uma classe, então um `ExpandoObject` trabalha com um dicionário, e para "pegar" suas propriedades por nome tem que fazer a conversão para dicionário, só acessar por chave direto não funciona, aparentemente o que estava acontecendo nessa linha: `lineToInsert[value]`

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigada!

Comment: Depois não esqueça de aceitar a resposta se ajudou